# Нужно ли сжимать скрипты и плагины в 1 файл

Tags: javascript, jquery, grunt, оптимизация-сайтов

Вопрос по оптимизации проекта. Использую grunt.js, все скрипты и плагины объединяю и сжимаю в один файл, правильно ли это? Либо нужно подключать отдельно плагины, а все вызовы плагинов и простые скрипты объединять уже в 1 файл?

Comment: если много весить будет уже файл "ядра" скажем так, то лучше и его разбивать на несколько файлов. Просто главное помнить, что каждое подключение файла (стиль, скрипт, изображение) это лишинй коннект к серверу который забирает время.

Comment: Ну необязательно 1 файл, сколько точек входа столько и бандлов

Comment: Также если как говорит OlmerDale Вы будете использовать современные инструменты (правильно настроенный вебпак и модули), то думать над тем на сколько правильно файлов бить и когда кусочек подгружать - за вас  в основном будет инструмент.

Comment: @user190134 в HTTP/2 все файлы передаются в пределах одного соединения, причём одновременно и параллельно

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму когда я тыкал модный нынче webpack, там с разбиением файлов на несколько было много нетривиальной асинхронной возни

Comment: @user190134 почему тогда в консоль -> сеть - на каждый файл есть поле "время загрузки" и сайт с 50подключениями разных скриптов грузит значительно дольше чем с 5ти скриптами?

Comment: @user190134 возможно потому что сайт не использует http2?

Comment: @user190134 почитал про HTTP2 - да, там все в рамках 1 соединения. Но я про 1.1 Говорил

Comment: @user190134 а не надо говорить про 1.1 в год, когда все браузеры и серверы уже умеют 2 :)

Comment: ну прям уж таки все

Comment: @andreymal, еще раз, если у вас пет проджект который вы пилите в одно лицо, то можно сказать, "а катимся на http2" и резко перекатиться, в обычных боевых задачах так сказать обычно нельзя.

Comment: @andreymal, разумеется было, потому что подгрузка файлов on-demand это и есть та самая асинхронная возня. И там где есть такая фича - будет асинхронная возня. Но на уровне инструмента, если Вы все нормально делаете, то эта возня вас не касается.

Answer (score 2):

Вы все верно делаете. Конкатенация скриптов и стилей уменьшает количество запросов на сервер, а также конечный размер `CSS` и `JS`, <s>что делает загрузку сайтов более быстрой, вследствие чего показатель отказов падает, позиции в поисковой выдаче растут, глубина просмотров растет, а клиент счастлив.</s>

#### Оптимизация стилей

Кроме обычной минификации стилей можно использовать и продвинутую - объединять дубликаты классов и @media. Пример на `gulp` из моего [web-starter-kit](https://github.com/1000tech/web-starter-kit):

```
var
    gulp = require('gulp'),
    stylus = require('gulp-stylus'),

    // Минифицирует CSS, объединяет классы. Не ломает CSS, в отличие от cssnano, который, к примеру, может неправильно выставлять z-index
    csso = require('gulp-csso'),

    // Объединяет все @media
    cmq = require('gulp-combine-mq'),

    // Сокращает CSS-селекторы    
    gs = require('gulp-selectors'),

    // Проставляет вендорные префиксы
    autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),

    livereload = require('gulp-livereload'),
    nib = require('nib');

// Compiling Stylus in CSS
gulp.task('css', function() {
    gulp.src('./styl/*.styl')
        .pipe(stylus({
            use: nib()
        }))
        .pipe(cmq())
        .pipe(csso())
        .pipe(autoprefixer('last 3 versions'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/css/'))
        .pipe(livereload())
});
```

А если совсем делать нечего, то можно еще и селекторы сократить:

```
// Minify selectors
    gulp.task('gs', function() {
        var ignores = {
            classes: ['active', 'menu', 'nav', 'slide', 'error', 'form-control', 'loader', 'showLoader', 'fadeLoader', 'webp', 'wow', 'owl-*', 'i-*'],
            ids: '*'
        };
        gulp.src(['./public/**/*.css', './public/**/*.html'])
            .pipe(gs.run({}, ignores))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/'))
    });
```

Кстати, наверняка у вас есть классы, добавляющиеся через JS, поэтому предварительно стоит все такие классы вынести в переменную `ignores`.

#### Сжатие графики

Кроме стилей и скриптов также посоветую сжимать и графику. К примеру, картинки можно легко сжать без потери качества только за счет удаление exif-данных. Пример на `gulp`:

```
var
    gulp = require('gulp'),
    imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin'),
    imageminJR = require('imagemin-jpeg-recompress'),
    imageminSvgo = require('imagemin-svgo');

// Optimizing images
gulp.task('imagemin', function() {
    gulp.src('./img/**/*')
        .pipe(imagemin([
            imageminJR({
                method: 'ms-ssim'
            }),
            imageminSvgo({
                plugins: [
                    {removeViewBox: false}
                ]
            })
        ]))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/img/'))
});
```

А для браузеров, которые понимают легковесный формат `webp` (формат разработан Google), можно сделать еще такой вариант изображений:

```
var
    gulp = require('gulp'),
    webp = require('gulp-webp');

// Generate Webp
gulp.task('webp', function() {
    gulp.src('./img/**/*')
        .pipe(webp())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/img/'))
});
```

#### Кеширование статики на стороне пользователя

Также бы посоветовал кешировать скрипты и стили на стороне пользователя, чтобы исключить их повторную загрузку, если они не изменились:

```
<FilesMatch ".(flv|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|ico|svg|swf|js|css|pdf|woff2|woff|ttf|eot)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000"
</FilesMatch>
```

И включить gzip сжатие на сервере:

```
# сжатие text, html, javascript, css, xml:
<ifModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml application/xml application/xhtml+xml text/css text/javascript application/javascript application/x-javascript
</ifModule>
```

#### Преимущества и недостатки CDN

С одной стороны `cdn` действительно поможет брать контент с кеша пользователя, однако с другой - это создаст дополнительный запрос, если этого контента у пользователя нет. Еще одна проблема может быть в том, что сервер `cdn` вовсе может не работать и ничего не отдать. Вспомнить хотя бы, как несколько лет назад все сервисы Google перестали работать и тысячи сайтов сломались из-за того, что не могли загрузить шрифты с Google Font.

В будущем, когда `HTTP/2` будет достаточно распространен, скрипты можно будет загружать в несколько потоков и конкатенация будет необязательной. Хотя и тогда конечный размер сжатых в один файлов будет эффективней, чем сжатых по отдельности.