# Какой выигрыш в скорости загрузки и быстродействии даст прямая вставка стилей и скриптов в HTML-файл?

Tags: javascript, html, css, оптимизация-сайтов

Нет, я и не думаю заниматься подобным олдскуллерским извращением вручную. Предположим, что мы с помощью какой-нибудь утилиты типа препроцессора заменили подключение стилей `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">` на прямую вставку стилей `<style type="text/css">...</style>`, а подключение скриптов опять же на прямую вставку кода в HTML-страницу. То есть теперь у нас и HTML, и стили, и JS находятся в одном файле, и нам не надо делать дополнительные запросы к серверу для стилей и скриптов. Какой это даст выигрыш в быстродействии и скорости загрузки страницы?

Comment: Почему обязательно "выигрыш"? Может "проигрыш". *(быстро произнесите много раз подряд эти два слова)*

Comment: @Igor, Так замечательно! Вы только скажите, что именно, и обоснуйте, и поставлю Вам галочку.

Comment: Даже как-то неудобно об этом говорить вслух. Скажем, стилей и скриптов - *много*. В отдельных файлах (в пределе - в двух) их можно пометить максимальным сроком жизни, и после первоначальной загрузки браузер будет брать их из своего кэша. Данные, вставленные в страницу, надо будет передавать каждый раз - если, конечно, страница не статическая.

Comment: @Igor, очень интересно... Правда, не до конца понятно. По сути всё от doctype и до закрывающего `</html>` - это просто длинная строка, которую возвращает сервер один раз в течение просмотра конкретной страницы. Поэтому не совсем ясно, что куда "передавать каждый раз"...

Comment: Почему просто не попробовать так и так и сравнить результаты?

Comment: "Передавать каждый раз" - как известно, при запросе какой-то странички в интернете `html` загружается каждый раз. А вот уже контент, который содержится на страничке - от картинок до скриптов и стилей - не грузится каждый раз. Если на страничке указана версия контента, которая уже есть в кэше браузера, и лайфтайм этого кэша не истек, то будет использована версия, что в кэше.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Нужно ли сжимать скрипты и плагины в 1 файл](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/613256/%d0%9d%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d0%b2-1-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если сервер отдает контент по `http 2.0` – то разницы никакой не будет, потому что данные будут отдаваться параллельно и не будут блокировать загрузку друг друга. Если же по `http 1.1` – то через инлайн-вставку мы уменьшим количество `http` запросов и ускорим загрузку контента в первый раз.

Однако стоит учитывать, что таким образом мы будем загружать `js` и `css` каждый раз с `html`-документом, тогда как внешние файлы мы могли бы закешировать на стороне пользователя.

Также есть смысл вынести некоторые критические стили в `<style type="text/css">...</style>`, чтобы не блокировать рендеринг html. Что такое `Critical rendering path`, подробно разобрано в [этой теме](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/636076/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-critical-rendering-path).

Если интересуют другие методы оптимизации фронта, то советую вам глянуть [мой ответ к этому вопросу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/639423/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0-front/639472#639472).

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ! Да, меня тема оптимизации фронтенда очень даже интересует.